# DoctrineBundle doesn't install on VM in Symfony 4.4

Tags: php, git, symfony

I work on a symfony 4.4 project and I needed to move my workspace to a virtual machine.

## Problem

### In my VM workspace

```sh
git clone https://gitlab.domaim.com/repo/myrepo.git
cd myrepo
php composer.phar install
```

Every bundle is installed correctly but at the end of the script when it try to clean cache it throws an error :

> Attempted to load class "DoctrineBundle" from namespace "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Weird because on the composer output it shows `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` but in `vendors/doctrine`, the `doctrine-bundle` folder is empty...

## What I tried

### In my Local workspace

I wanted to try the same commands in my local environnement and here every thing works fine...

In both environments, I have the same php version `PHP-7.2.30` and the `APP_ENV` is set to `dev` in both too.

I really don't understand what's happening. Thanks for help

**EDIT: My `composer.json`**

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "anyx/login-gate-bundle": "^0.7.1",
        "damienharper/doctrine-audit-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "2.3.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
        "onurb/excel-bundle": "^1.0",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.10",
        "shivas/versioning-bundle": "^3.2",
        "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/ldap": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.5",
        "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.7",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
        "twig/twig": "^2.0",
        "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "^1.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.14",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "Sii\\DeliveryBundle\\": "libraries/delivery"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Sii\\DeliveryBundle\\": "libraries/delivery"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide us your composer.json. Is your composer.lock well synchronized with your composer.json? Does this error happen when you do `composer update`?

Comment: Hey thanks ! Well for both install to be sure I deleted `composer.lock` and run `composer.phar install`. So I think the error can't be due to `composer.lock`. I've edited my main message with composer.json

Comment: Is the bundle enabled in `bundles.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

The use error is common if you do not add a Bundle manually to your config/bundles.php. For Doctrine Bundle there should be an array element like:

```
Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

If you use [symfony flex](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/setup.html#installing-packages), then the bundles is automatically added on first install through composer